# How do I split a large Pages document into multiple Pages documents

Tags: pages

I have a rather large Pages document that has many sections. 
I need to break each of those sections out into their own Pages documents.

I am using `Pages 5.5.3`.

Can this be done easily? Right now I'm in cut and paste mode.

Answer (score 1):

Although you could script this in AppleScript since Pages is scriptable, I've never had enough sections to make the time spent crafting a script worth the time needed to figure out the syntax.

I simply duplicate the document as many times as needed in finder, batch rename them using Finder.

If you had 64 sections, I would use a "binary search" approach.

- split the document in 2
- split in 4
- split by 8
- split by half

I've never liked copy/paste since things get odd sometimes. Chopping out the unneeded parts always seems to work better for me, but your manual copy/paste method also will work.

Comment: That's an interesting approach to the problem.

Comment: @dennis.hempler Sorry to offer a brute force approach. The zip file and xml  structure of a pages document makes the tools I would normally use poor choices.